# "malformed locale" error when merging document

Tags: civicase, printmerge

We're using CiviCase as a project tracker and document generator. It has been working fine, but I had to recently move the site to a new server. The directory structure, domain, database all stayed the same, but it's a new OS install on a new VPS.
When we run "Print/Merge Document" on the "Manage Case" page, the task fails with the error "Cannot instantiate malformed locale: EN". There is a little more info in the CiviCRM log, but it doesn't tell me anything more that I can make sense of. I assume there is some issue with the php or system locale, but I can't figure out what.

Any thoughts?

CiviCRM log:

```
Oct 02 16:21:24  [error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Cannot instantiate malformed locale: EN"
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#11809
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Cannot instantiate malformed locale: EN"
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Locale.php"
    #line: 177
    trace: {
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/Locale.php:177 {
        Civi\Core\Locale::negotiate(string $preferred): Locale
        › if (!preg_match(';^[a-z][a-z]_[A-Z][A-Z]$;', $preferred)) {
        ›   throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Cannot instantiate malformed locale: $preferred");
        › }
      }
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Subscriber/I18nSubscriber.php:61 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:251 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:260 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:249 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:157 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php:249 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php:484 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php:345 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php:271 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/PDFTrait.php:240 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:612 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:153 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php:120 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php:98 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:292 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:334 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
      /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
    }
  }
]


Oct 02 16:21:24  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#3 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(334): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /var/www/civi.waccglobal.org/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main}
```

We're running on WordPress 6.3.1 on Debian 12 (bookworm).
CiviCRM version 5.63.2. Yes I do need to upgrade. However, experience has shown I should fix errors before doing so.

Comment: It's expecting something like en_US not just "en". The question is where is it getting that from. The rest of the stacktrace might actually be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @demerit I've included the full trace now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah that does help. It's likely one of the contacts has a malformed preferred_language on their contact where it has EN instead of en_SOMETHING.

From https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/c3a9a0894c3702d961d4bcaf61a3404e66c56371/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php#L343

You can run a query on the database like `SELECT id FROM civicrm_contact WHERE preferred_language = 'EN'` to find the contact id.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like every English  contact was set as EN. It must have been acceptable on the previous server. Changed every one to en_US and now documents generate fine.